# Ho to make a bootable disk image to test bootloader with vmware?

Tags: assembly, vmware, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

I made a simple bootloader but I have no idea about testing this with vmware.

It works well in bochs. But I have to test this with vmware.

So I am trying to make a bootable disk image file, but I don't know what to do.

```
; loader.asm

%macro setline 1
   mov al, 0x0a
   int 0x10
   mov ah, 0x02
   mov bh, 0
   mov dl, 0
   mov dh, %1
   int 0x10
%endmacro

[org 0x7c00]

cli

mov bp, 0x7c00
mov sp, bp

mov bx, null
call bios_writestr
setline 18

mov bx, logstr_1
call bios_writestr
setline 19

mov bx, logstr_2
call bios_writestr
setline 20

jmp $

bios_writestr:
   mov ah, 0x0e
   .Loop:
   cmp [bx], byte 0
   je .Exit
      mov al, [bx]
      int 0x10
      inc bx
      jmp .Loop
   .Exit:
   ret

null: db 0
logstr_1: db 'Hello, world', 0
logstr_2: db 'Hello! World!', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xaa
```

Compilation:

```
nasm -f bin loader.asm -o loader.bin
```

Then what am I going to do? I want to test it in vmware.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way of converting your `.bin` file to `.iso` without breaking things, you can use an real world bootloader like [Grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/), [Limine](https://github.com/limine-bootloader/limine), [BOOTBOOT](https://gitlab.com/bztsrc/bootboot), ETC... There some guides for using them for your OS: Like this [one](https://wiki.osdev.org/GRUB) for Grub.